# Template version and non-template version of the same function

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following simple function

```
void foo_rt(int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        // ... do something relatively cheap ...
    }
}
```

If I know the parameter `n` at compiletime, I can write a template version of the same function:

```
template<int n>
void foo_ct() {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        // ... do something relatively cheap ...
    }
}
```

This allows the compiler to do things like loop unrolling, which increases speed.

But assume now that I *sometimes* know `n` at compiletime and *sometimes* only at runtime.  How can I implement this without maintaining two versions of the function? I was thinking something along the lines:

```
inline void foo(int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        // ... do something relatively cheap ...
    }
}

// Runtime version
void foo_rt(int n) { foo(n); }

// Compiletime version
template<int n>
void foo_ct() { foo(n); }
```

But I am not sure if all compilers are smart enough to deal with this. Is there a better way?

EDIT:

Clearly, one solution that will work is to use macros, but this I *really* want to avoid:

```
#define foo_body \
{ \
    for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) { \
        // ... do something relatively cheap ... \
    } \
}

// Runtime version
void foo_rt(int n) foo_body

// Compiletime version
template<int n>
void foo_ct() foo_body
```

Comment: Your solution changes nothing, it just adds a level of indirection.

Comment: I think the compiler is smarter than you at optimization. Don't bother with things like this it just makes the code harder to read. Note: loop unrolling will be done whether the value is run-time (the compiler is aware of duffs-device) or compile-time defined depending on other factors not in your control. What you are doing is not going to help the compiler either way.

Comment: The inline version should be enough for compiler to make his optimization, like loop unrolling.

Comment: @LokiAstari This is in a very performance critical part of the code (it's the implementation of a virtual machine), and the code becomes a great deal faster when the parameter is known at compile time.

Comment: If you have unit tests that prove that. Then sure. Use your technique and document why you are doing it and how to prove it so you can test it holds on other platforms. But since loop-unrolling is going to happen anyway I think there might be something else you are not telling us.

Comment: @LokiAstari Sure, it's not just about loop unrolling. Sections of the code disappears if `n` is 0 for example. And in fact, there are more than one integer parameter and large simplifications are possible when any of them is either 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this before, using a `integral_variable` type and `std::integral_constant`.  This looks like a lot of code, but if you look again, it's actually only a series of four very simple pieces, one of which is merely demo code.

```
#include <type_traits>

//type for acting like integeral_constant but with a variable
template<class underlying>
struct integral_variable {
    const underlying value;
    integral_variable(underlying v) :value(v) {}
}; 

//generic function
template<class value> 
void foo(value n) {
    for(int i=0; i<n.value; ++i) {
        // ... do something relatively cheap ...
    }
} 

//optional: specialize so callers don't have to do casts
void foo_rt(int n) { return foo(integral_variable<int>(n)); }
template<int n>
void foo_ct() { return foo(std::integral_constant<unsigned, n>()); }
//notice it even handles different underlying types.  Doesn't care.

//usage is simple
int main() {
    foo_rt(3);
    foo_ct<17>();
}
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for enlightenment!

Comment: I believe `n::value` should be `n.value`. Also I think this technique should only make a difference when the function does not get inlined.

Comment: @bames53: good eye on the `.`, but even when inlining is not happening, there's lots of optimizations that can happen.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to imply that this technique isn't useful. Relying on a function getting inlined may not be a good idea, and inlining may not even be desirable for code size reasons. Although if a compiler is clever enough then inlining may not be necessary. E.g., see the the new inter-procedural constant propagation in GCC 4.7: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html

Answer (score 1):

Much as I admire the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I don't think there's a way around writing it twice.

Even though the code is the same, these are two very different operations -- working with a known value versus working with an unknown value.

You want to put the known one on a fast track to optimization that the unknown one may not qualify for.

What I would do is factor out all the code that does not depend on n into another function (which hopefully is the entire body of your `for` loop), and then have both your templated and non-templated versions call that within their loops.  That way, the only thing you're repeating is the structure of the `for` loop, which I wouldn't consider a big deal.

Comment: A generic algorithm can handle it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If a value is known at compile time routing it through a template as a template parameter doesn't make it any *more* known at compile time. I think it's very unlikely that there are any compilers out there that will inline and optimize a function simply because the variable is a template parameter rather than some other kind of compile time constant.

Depending on your compiler you may not even need two versions of the function. An optimizing compiler may well just be able to optimize a function called with constant expression parameters. For example:

```
extern volatile int *I;

void foo(int n) {
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
        *I = i;
}

int main(int argc,char *[]) {
    foo(4);
    foo(argc);
}
```

My compiler turns this into an inlined, unrolled loop from 0 to 3, followed by an inlined loop on argc:

```
main:                                   # @main
# BB#0:                                 # %entry
        movq    I(%rip), %rax
        movl    $0, (%rax)
        movl    $1, (%rax)
        movl    $2, (%rax)
        movl    $3, (%rax)
        testl   %ecx, %ecx
        jle     .LBB1_3
# BB#1:                                 # %for.body.lr.ph.i
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movq    I(%rip), %rdx
        .align  16, 0x90
.LBB1_2:                                # %for.body.i4
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        movl    %eax, (%rdx)
        incl    %eax
        cmpl    %eax, %ecx
        jne     .LBB1_2
.LBB1_3:                                # %_Z3fooi.exit5
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        ret
```

To get such optimizations you either need to ensure the definition is available to all translation units (e.g., by defining the function as inline in a header file), or have a compiler that does link-time optimization.

If you use this and you're really depending on some things being computed at compile time then you should have automated tests to verify it gets done.

---

C++11 provides constexpr, which allows you to write a function that will be computed at compile time when given constexpr parameters, or to guarantee that a value is computed at compile time. There are restriction on what can go in a constexpr function, which may make it difficult to implement your function as a constexpr, but the allowed language is apparently turing complete. One issue is that, while the restrictions guarantee that the computation can be done at compile time if given constexpr parameters, those restrictions may result in an inefficient implementation for when the parameters are *not* constexpr.

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like:

```
template<typename getter>
void f(getter g)
{
   for (int i =0; i < g.get(); i++) { blah(); }
}

struct getter1 { inline constexpr int get() { return 1; } }
struct getterN { getterN(): _N(N) {} inline constexpr int get() { return k; } }
f<getter1>(getter1());
f<getterN>(getterN(100));
```

Answer (score -1):

I would point out that if you have:

```
// Runtime version
void foo_rt(int n){ foo(n);}
```

... and this works for you, then you **do** in fact know the type at compile time.  At least, you know a type that it is covariant with, and that's all you need to know.  You can just use the templated version.  If need be, you can specify the type at the call site, like this:

```
foo_rt<int>()
```

Comment: I think the OP was passing the `n` as a compile time parameter to the template not the fact that it was an integer.

Comment: Could be, hard to tell.  I'll let OP chime in on this before I remove this answer.

Comment: Yes. The type is known (`int` in this case), so you could call the function `foo_ct<3>` for example.